# How to use "\w+" to find words in a string?

Tags: regex, scala

I need to write a function that takes a string as input. This function will return a List[String]. I have to use the regular expression "\w+" in this function as a requirement for this task. So when given a line string of random text with a few actual words dotted around inside it, I need to add all of these 'proper' words and add them to the list to be returned. I must also use ".findAllIn". I have tried the following

```
def foo(stringIn: String) : List[String] = {
    val regEx = """\w+""".r
    val match = regEx.findAllIn(s).toList
    match
}
```

But it just returns the string that I pass into the function.

Comment: can you please share your full code of the function

Comment: That is everything @Jatin

Comment: what is the string that you are passing?

Comment: foo("hjadhcahhcdehellokhdbchbvsworldkbhjwbff")

Comment: That's because your regex `\w+` matches your entire string.

Comment: If the answer satisfies your questio, @k1888914 can you please accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`match` is a reserved keyword in scala. So you just need to replace that.

```
def foo(stringIn: String) : List[String] = {
    val regEx = """\w+""".r
    regEx.findAllIn(stringIn).toList
}

scala> foo("hey. how are you?")
res17: List[String] = List(hey, how, are, you)
```

`\\w` is the [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a word character, in the current regex context equal to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, that matches a lower- and uppercase letters, digits and an underscore.

`\\w+` is for one ore more occurrences of the above.

```
scala> foo("hey")
res18: List[String] = List(hey)
```

In above case, there is nothing for the regex to split by. Hence returns the original string.

```
scala> foo("hey-hey")
res20: List[String] = List(hey, hey)
```

`-` is not part of `\\w`. Hence it splits by `-`

Comment: Ahhh ok I understand, my bad I am new to Scala and didn't really understand the task at hand. Thank you everyone.